# unable to install virtual box on fedora 32

Tags: fedora, virtualbox

i was watching this course on ethical hacking on udemy and  started installing virtual box through the following steps.

1. i installed free and non free rpm fusion repositories through command line setup using rpm by using the command given in the website https://rpmfusion.org/configuration
2. used the command yum search virtualbox

3)The guy in the course asked to install a package that looked like "kmod-virtualbox-5.8.6-201.fc32.x86_64:virtualbox kernel module(s) for 5.8.6-201.fc32.x86_64"

4. since i couldnt find a package like that, i installed something similar" kmod-virtualbox.x86_64:metapackage which tracks in virtualbox kernel module for newest kernel"

5)Then i couldnt find virtualbox installed in my computer

6)Then i downloaded virtualbox directly from the website "https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/linux_downloads" to my defaults download folder.

7)When i double clicked the downloaded file in the folder to install it, it redirected to the SOFTWARE application which came with the os and showed the app there.

8)I clicked on install there, but it prompted the following message "unable to install virtualbox error running transaction:file/usr/bin/vbox from install of virtualbox-6.1-6.1.14_14039_fedora32-1.x84_64 conflicts with file from package virtualbox-server-6.1.14_1.fc32-1.x84_64"

the above description is exactly how it happened. please help me resolve this issue and download virtualbox

Comment: @roaima - are you sure? Every package that's mentioned by the OP ends with **x86_64**.

Comment: Remove all of the VB packages, then try again with the version you downloaded from Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you reinstall your Fedora 32 from scratch as a first step. If you can't do it:

```
dnf remove $(rpm -qa | grep -i virtualbox)
dnf install https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.1.14/VirtualBox-6.1-6.1.14_140239_fedora32-1.x86_64.rpm
```

Both commands must be run under root or `sudo`.

Comment: This helped installing virtualbox. But , didnt quite understand the problem. Thanks anyways.